# Find the orthogonal trajectories of a function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The function which I need to find the orthogonal trajectories to is: $\quad y = x^3 + c$

So I derive the function: 
$$y'= 3x^2$$

Then I get from the original equation: 
$$y' = \frac{3(y-C)}{x}$$

The DE of the orthogonal function: 
$$y' = \frac{-x}{3(y-C)}$$

the separable equation is 
$$(y-C)\,dy = \frac{-x}{3}\,dx$$

after integration
$$\frac{y^2}{2} - C y = \frac{-x^2}{6}$$

Explaining $y$ from this equation: 
$$y = \sqrt{C^2 - \frac{x^2}{3}} + c^2$$

Plotting this equation and the original using the parameter of $\,c=3\,$ I can't see the orthogonality. What did do I wrong? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately take the negative reciprocal without substituting anything:
$$
y = x^3 + C \implies y' = 3x^2 ~~\xrightarrow{\textsf{negative reciprocal}}~~ y' = \frac{-1}{3x^2} \implies y =\frac{1}{3x} + D
$$

Comment: But there is one thing I can't understand. Value of D should be the C from the original equation. But how can I determine this exactly?